# Force Elasticsearch to return 404 on non-existence document meeting search conditions

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using `ElasticSearch 6.2`.  Is it possible to force ElasticSearch to return `404` (or something different than `200`) in case of lack of document meeting search constraints?
In other words:
`GET /twitter/_search?q=user:kimchy`
Instead of `200 OK` with body containing empty list of results I would like to get `404`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can not. Also, IMHO it's not correct from point of HTTP request.

You can check return data on the program side and do what you want if result data is empty